# "I'm __" to express disagreement and "I'm __" to express agreement

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I would like a single word to use in "*I'm __*" to express disagreement and a different single word to use in "*I'm __*" to express agreement.

*I am looking for a pair of words that are intuitive opposites of each other.*

For example, suppose I'm for (or against) drug legalisation:

> Jack: What do you think about drug legalisation?
>     Me: Well, I have to say I'm __ .

Of course I may just say "I'm for it" or "I'm against it", but besides this, what else (preferably a single word) can fill this blank? Initially I thought I could say "I'm pro" or "I'm con", which however turns out wrong since according to OED "pro/con" is used to describe a thing (dis/advantage) rather than a person (opp/proponent).

Comment: Well, I have to say I'm *against*.

Comment: @JohnClifford against is a preposition I suppose?

Comment: Yes: fully-written it would be "I'm against [drug legalisation]" but you can determine the noun phrase from context so it can be elided.

Comment: You may sometimes see *yea* and *nay*.

Comment: @GEdgar *I'm* yea/nay?

Comment: The Yiddish word "farblondzhet" is really tempting...

Comment: I can't think of proper English versions but the kids would say:I'm anti/down. (down being the positive).

Comment: I can't think of a single word for being "in agreement" (though "I'm for it" or "I'm in favor of it" are both short, common ways to express it), but for disagreement, the single word "opposed" works.

Comment: You can say "I'm opposed" or "I'm opposed to it".  On the positive side, you can say "I'm in favor", "I'm in favor of it", or "I favor it".

Comment: @Mari-LouA no you misunderstand me. I don't mean the same time. I mean separately. Btw, is I'm pro grammatically ok? I think pro is not used to describe a person, though.

Comment: Used in an informal setting, to declare oneself "pro something" is acceptable See here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=I%27m+%22pro+choice%22&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj80PO6t_nLAhXEK5oKHZmqAUoQsAQIGw

Comment: There is no one word that means  to be "[in favour of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/favour#favour__8) XYZ" or "against XYZ", I doubt that it exists in any language, I'd be interested to know if it does. Note that Oxford cites "pro" as a synonym for *in favour of*

Comment: The only usage with a single word that comes to my mind is _I'm game_ to express agreement/willingness. However, I believe this is regarded as slang.

Answer (score 1):

You can use active instead of passive voice, and use ***agree*** and ***disagree***.

> I ***agree*** [*with this*].
>
> I ***disagree*** [*with that*].

If forced to use passive voice, I would opt for *unopposed* and ***opposed***, but *unopposed* still sounds stilted given the more natural idiomatic usage ***in favor***.

Answer (score -1):

There's [agreeable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agreeable) and its opposite, disagreeable.

Unfortunately, *agreeable* has several related meanings, so the result could be a bit ambiguous.  People could take "I'm agreeable" as meaning "I'm an easy person to get along with", rather than "I'm able to agree to that".